# Select element with Control + left mouse click in Android Studio code editor

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

In Android Studio I've disabled the "Navigate to declaration" shortcut for Control + mouse Click action. How do I make that combination behave like double click - select the element under cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to rebind `Extend Selection`, which by default is CTRL-w.